# O que é o Metabot e qual sua função no SOPTmeta?

Tags: debate, chat

Recentemente um usuário do chat chamado Metabot enviou um link no chat do SOPT, é um roobot, qual sua função ?

Comment: Metabot é um bot do meta que republica perguntas postadas aqui lá no chat.

Comment: Massa, desculpe a curiosidade, pq vc postou sua resposta no comentário e não na resposta?

Comment: Não gosto muito de responder perguntas no meta, prefiro deixar pros mais veteranos do site.

Comment: A função dele é colocar no chat as novas publicações aqui do meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, ele é um robô. Não sei bem como funciona, mas sempre que aparece alguma postagem  nova aqui no Meta, ele nos avisa gentilmente lá no chat.

Parece que o nome @MetaBot foi um trocadilho com a palavra "Meta" (por causa do Meta Stackoverflow) e "bot" por que ele age como um robô.

E para entender mais ainda o trocadilho, existe um anime chamado Medabots, da qual foi tirada a foto do perfil.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Metabeeee! Medaforça! :D